# Java 8 stream get embedded object

Tags: java-8

I have a list of myObjects

```
List<MyObject> myObjects
```

and I will have all OtherObject's

```
class MyObject {

     private OtherObject otherObject;
}
```

My simple approach was:

```
myObjects.stream().??
```

but I do not know how to get that embedded objects

Comment: Dont know exactly what you try to do ... But myObjects.stream().map(c->c.getOtherObject()); gives you a stream of you embedded objects. Ofcause you need a getter method for this embedded objects. Is that what you wanna do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
         HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
         myObjects.add(hw.new MyObject("Try"));
         myObjects.add(hw.new MyObject("This"));
         myObjects.stream()
         .map(o -> o.getOtherObject().toUpperCase())
         .forEach(System.out::println);

     }

    class MyObject {
        private String otherObject;
        public MyObject(String s) {
            this.otherObject = s;
        }
        public String getOtherObject() {
            return otherObject;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter to `MyObject` and use `map`

```
class MyObject {

    private OtherObject otherObject;

    public OtherObject getOtherObject() {
        return otherObject;
    }
}

...
myObjects.stream().map(MyObject::getOtherObject).forEach(System.out::println)
```